# Providing id values for each option in ng-options

Tags: angularjs, select, ng-options

I have a select box that looks like this:

```
 <select ng-model="ctrl.arrayVal" ng-options="option for option in ctrl.myarray"></select>
```

where ctrl.myarray looks something like:

```
ctrl.myarray = [100, 200, 700, 900];
```

This all works great, but for automated testing purposes I need to provide an id to each of the dynamically generated options. So for example if I rewrote this using `ng-repeat` then I would need something like this:

```
<select ng-model="ctrl.arrayVal"> 
   <option id="array-{{option}}" ng-repeat="option in ctrl.myarray" value="{{option}}">{{option}}</option>
</select>
```

Notice the `array-{{option}}` id that is possible in this second snippet using `ng-repeat`. I need to provide a similar id but using the first `ng-options` method.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently `ng-options` only lets you specify the `value` property of the `<option>` element using the select `as` or `track by` syntax.  It is also possible to add the `disabled` property if your data source is an object (not an array). It is not possible to further customize the fields of the `<option>` element including `id`.

[Docs on ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can achieve your goal with a custom directive. For example:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.directive('idAdder', function() {
  return {

    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function() {
        scope.$evalAsync(function() {
          angular.forEach(element.find('option'), function(o, k) {
            o.id = o.value;
          });
        });
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Then, use it as a custom attribute:

```
 <select ng-model="ctrl.arrayVal" 
         ng-options="option for option in ctrl.myarray"
         id-adder></select>
```

The `$watch` and `$evalAsync`are used to execute the function after the options have been populated/created.